# DevExpress ASPxTreeList - inline editing

Tags: c#, webforms, devexpress, asp.net-4.5

I'm trying to accomplish *inline editing* with a DevExpress ASPxTreeList control on an ASP.NET 4.5 webforms application - something like this (taken from the DevExpress demo site):

[image]

What I'm trying to do are two things:

1. I'd like to be able to restrict my inline editing to just a few columns - e.g. **only** the `Budget` column should be editable. I'd like to have **only** the `Budget` cell turn into a textbox to allow data entry - while all other columns in the chosen row should remain *as is* - as labels basically (right now, when I enable inline editing, *all* cells turn into editable controls - they turn into a textbox that would suggest editing is possible)
2. I would love to be able to just click (or double-click) into that cell to enable inline editing - for now, I need to use a separate command button to "turn on" editing. How can I do this (if at all)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want labels instead of editable controls, then you can simply use `EditCellTemplate` with label control inside.

Here is example:

```xml
<dx:TreeListDataColumn FieldName="ContactName">
    <EditCellTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ContactName") %>' />
    </EditCellTemplate>
</dx:TreeListDataColumn>
```

2. This functionality for `ASPxTreeList` does not implemented by DevExpress. They have suggestion in their Support Center to implement «[ASPxTreeList - Implement BatchEdit mode (like in ASPxGridView)](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S173524)». [Here](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/BatchEditing.aspx) you can take a look at how it works in `ASPxGridView`.

So, here is workaround, based on [this](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E324) example.
The main goal is to use `DataCellTemplate` for columns with `ASPxTextBox` control as value editor. The `ASPxTextBox` can be fully customized by applying a specific style to each composite editor element. This allows to simulate the desired behavior. You can hide the borders and background of `ASPxTextBox` and show the borders only when `ASPxTextBox` is focused.
Here is example:

```xml
<script>
    function GotFocus(s, e) {
        s.inputElement.style.cursor = "text";
    }
    function LostFocus(s, e) {
        s.inputElement.style.cursor = "default";
    }
</script>

<dx:ASPxTreeList ID="ASPxTreeList1" ClientInstanceName="tree" runat="server" Width="100%"
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="CategoryID"
    OnCustomCallback="ASPxTreeList1_CustomCallback">            
        <Columns>
            <dx:TreeListTextColumn FieldName="CategoryID" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="0">
            </dx:TreeListTextColumn>
            <dx:TreeListTextColumn FieldName="CategoryName" VisibleIndex="1">
                <DataCellTemplate>
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox
                        ID="txtBox"
                        Width="100%"
                        runat="server"
                        Value='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>'
                        Cursor="default"
                        BackColor="Transparent"
                        Border-BorderColor="Transparent"
                        FocusedStyle-Border-BorderColor="ActiveBorder"
                        ClientSideEvents-GotFocus="GotFocus"
                        ClientSideEvents-LostFocus="LostFocus" />
                </DataCellTemplate>
            </dx:TreeListTextColumn>
            <dx:TreeListTextColumn FieldName="Description" VisibleIndex="2">
                <DataCellTemplate>                    
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox 
                        ID="txtBox" 
                        Width="100%" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Value='<%# Eval("Description")%>' 
                        Cursor="default"
                        BackColor="Transparent"
                        Border-BorderColor="Transparent"                        
                        FocusedStyle-Border-BorderColor="ActiveBorder"
                        ClientSideEvents-GotFocus="GotFocus"
                        ClientSideEvents-LostFocus="LostFocus"/>
                </DataCellTemplate>                                   
            </dx:TreeListTextColumn>
        </Columns>            
        <Border BorderWidth="0px" />
    </dx:ASPxTreeList>
    <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Text="Post Modifications"
        Width="217px">
        <ClientSideEvents Click="
function(s, e) {
    tree.PerformCallback('post');
}" />
    </dx:ASPxButton>

<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/nwind.mdb"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Categories]" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Categories] SET [CategoryName] = ?, [Description] = ? WHERE [CategoryID] = ?">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

```cs
private List<Record> list = new List<Record>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var column1 = ASPxTreeList1.DataColumns["CategoryName"];
    var column2 = ASPxTreeList1.DataColumns["Description"];

    var nodes = ASPxTreeList1.GetVisibleNodes();

    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        var txtBox1 = (ASPxTextBox)ASPxTreeList1.FindDataCellTemplateControl(node.Key, column1, "txtBox");
        var txtBox2 = (ASPxTextBox)ASPxTreeList1.FindDataCellTemplateControl(node.Key, column2, "txtBox");

        if (txtBox1 == null || txtBox2 == null)
            continue;

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(node.Key);
        list.Add(new Record(id, txtBox1.Text, txtBox2.Text));
    }
}

protected void ASPxTreeList1_CustomCallback(object sender, TreeListCustomCallbackEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Argument == "post")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            AccessDataSource1.UpdateParameters["CategoryName"].DefaultValue = list[i].CategoryName;
            AccessDataSource1.UpdateParameters["Description"].DefaultValue = list[i].Description;
            AccessDataSource1.UpdateParameters["CategoryID"].DefaultValue = list[i].Id.ToString();
            //                AccessDataSource1.Update();  << Uncomment this line to update data!
        }

        ASPxTreeList1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution for question #1 is perfect and works flawlessly - thank you so much